# Comparing start dates and end dates using SQL in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to compare start dates and end dates to make sure that start dates aren't later than end dates.
Tried posting onto sas community website, but too many post restrictions errors

table:

```
start_date 

1-Mar-19
```

I have included the proc sql/quit thing, but it gives me "ERROR: Function SUBSTRING_INDEX could not be located."

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(start_date, '-', 1) AS day
    ,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(start_date, '-', 2), '-',-1) as       month
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(start_date, '-', -1) as year 
FROM    mylib.sheet1
;
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `start` and `end`?  Is this in SAS or are you passing through to another database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff varchar, and it's SQL in SAS

Comment: There is no function `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` in SAS.  And why would you apply a substring function to a DATE value?

Comment: @Tom I was using substring_index() in SQL in SAS. The date format is in 9-Dec-2019 and such, which to my understanding isn't a standard date format

Comment: Doesn't matter whether you are calling the function in SQL or in a data step or a procedure that supports code statements you still need to use valid SAS functions. Unless you are using PROC SQL to explicitly push SQL code into some remote database.  But then you need to ask about how to do your operation in that language instead of in SAS.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I have included the Proc SQL/QUIT statements surrounding the SQL code (this info is in the post). I am asking about SQL while also providing context that the SQL is being used within SAS. Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: There are as many dialects of SQL as there are computer languages/systems that implement it.  The basic syntax of the implementations are similar, but the functions not specified in the definition of SQL (like any substring or date manipulations functions) are NOT part of SQL itself, but the language you are running. When you use PROC SQL you are still using SAS so you need to use SAS functions and follow SAS's rules for how to operate on dates and other values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have date variables just compare the values.

```
start_date <= end_date
```

If you have strings instead of dates then first convert them into date values. Then you can compare them.

```
input(start_string,date9.) <= input(end_string,date9.)
```